# Unix command to print log files in a directory

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to be able to go into a directory and print a file with a particular name, then sleep for 10, then print another file and sleep for 10. Each of the files will end in yesterdaysdate(YYYYMMDD).log

cd home/myfiles/apps/log

val1=`date +%Y%m%d --date="yesterday"`

pseudo code:

-use a for loop to print each file in the directory that is "*$val1.log"

-sleep 10  //sleep 10 after each file is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go.. not sure about the `cat $f` as I haven't tried it yet, but should be close to what you are asking for (using *val1* as specified).

edit: Have checked the code to work and simplified it a bit. Note the `clear`: it will erase all information from screen to before printing the next file.

```
val1=$(date +%Y%m%d --date="yesterday")
FILES=`ls ./*$val1.log`
for f in $FILES
do
    clear
    cat $f
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Exactly what I required. One question though. Why is ./ required before $val1.log?

Comment: The ./ is not mandatory to use. It would be sufficient to use `ls` without. I added it, however, for reasons of clarity (i.e. reading the current working directory).